# .then() not waiting for all promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, three.js

I'm Loading multiple gltf models using an async function and then using `.then()` I iterate through the results and add the models to my scene. It works perfectly fine until I remove one of the models from the source (the model I want to remove is larger than the rest), when I remove the model it seems like it's not waiting for all the promises to resolve before calling `.then()`. Below is the loader function, what am I doing wrong?

'source' is just an array of objects containing the model file paths

The error occurs in the `.then()`. If I remove one of the models (which is largest in size) from the 'source' array I get an error in the console: 'variant.components is not iterable'

```
async function modelLoader(source, loadingManager) {
    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
      promises.push(
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          const model = {}
          gltfLoader.load(source[i].file, (gltf) => {
            const children = [...gltf.scene.children];
            console.log(children);
              model.components = children;
            resolve(model);
          });
          if (source[i].type === 'baseModel' || (source[i].type === 'variant' && source[i].viewPoints.file !== 'none')) {
            gltfLoader.load(source[i].viewPoints.file, (gltf) => {
              const viewPoints = [...gltf.scene.children];
                model.viewPoints = viewPoints;
              resolve(model);
            });
          } else if (source[i].type === 'baseModel' || (source[i].type === 'variant' && source[i].viewPoints.file === 'none')) {
            model.viewPoints = 'none';
          } else if (source[i].type === 'land') {
            gltfLoader.load(source[i].buildingLine, (gltf) => {
              const buildingLine = [...gltf.scene.children]
              model.buildingLine = buildingLine
              resolve(model)
            })
          }
        })
      );
    }
    return await Promise.all(promises);
  }
```

```
const allModels = modelLoader(source, loadingManager)

allModels.then(result => {
    for (const variant of result) {
        if (variant.type === 'baseModel') {
            const house = new THREE.Group()
            for (const components of variant.components) {
                house.add(components)
            }       
        }                       
    }
})
```

Comment: JSYK because your function is already async the `await` in `return await` is redundant.

Comment: There's no `.then()` in the posted code.

Comment: You're calling `resolve()` from multiple places. You can only resolve a promise once.

Comment: Please make sure you code is **minimal**. It has a ton of extra clutter; boil it down so it include only relevant code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: No errors in console? You should show us also where you do this removal of the model and how you await that change -- i assume you call this function again? Essentially we also need to see where and how this function is used.

Comment: I've added the `.then()` part of my code where the error occurs.

Comment: @adsy I'm removing the model manually from the array of models I have, I simply just don't need that model anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across the same issue, I found the solution, using await on each call of the gltfLoader fixed the issue.

```
  async function modelLoader(source, loadingManager) {
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
const models = [];

for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
  const model = {
    name: source[i].name,
    type: source[i].type,
    isDefault: source[i].isDefault,
    section: source[i].section,
    isDetached: source[i].isDetached,
    isInterior: source[i].isInterior,
    price: source[i].price,
    image: source[i].image,
  };

  const gltf = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    gltfLoader.load(source[i].file, (gltf) => {
      resolve(gltf);
    });
  });

  const children = [...gltf.scene.children];
  model.components = children;

  if (
    source[i].type === 'baseModel' ||
    (source[i].type === 'variant' && source[i].viewPoints.file !== 'none')
  ) {
    const viewPointsGltf = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      gltfLoader.load(source[i].viewPoints.file, (gltf) => {
        resolve(gltf);
      });
    });

    const viewPoints = [...viewPointsGltf.scene.children];
    model.viewPoints = viewPoints;
  } else if (
    source[i].type === 'baseModel' ||
    (source[i].type === 'variant' && source[i].viewPoints.file === 'none')
  ) {
    model.viewPoints = 'none';
  } else if (source[i].type === 'land') {
    const buildingLineGltf = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      gltfLoader.load(source[i].buildingLine, (gltf) => {
        resolve(gltf);
      });
    });

    const buildingLine = [...buildingLineGltf.scene.children];
    model.buildingLine = buildingLine;
  }

  models.push(model);
}

return models;
```

}